# Wordpress URL rewrites using Advanced Custom Field

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, advanced-custom-fields

I've been working on this for a couple of days now. There have been many similar solutions here on this site, but none of them have worked out for me, or they nearly do, but then something else breaks.

For example, I tried this method: [Using Custom Fields in Custom Post Type URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67021/using-custom-fields-in-custom-post-type-url)

But when I finally got it working, every page on the site which wasn't specifically an "accommodation" CPT returned 404 pages.

What I'm trying to do is to rewrite the URLs for accommodation pages from:
/accommodation/%accommodation%/

to:
/%country%/%region%/%accommodation%/

I also need to do the same for Region CPTs (/region/%region%/ => /%country%/%region%/) but haven't managed to get the accommodation rewrites fully working yet.

As part of the build, I have an ACF custom field for Post Object, which returns the post ID of selected country and region CPTs; this is already used in the build to pull in related content, etc.
So for that reason, it makes sense to use these ACF fields to determine the values that need to go into the URL structure.

Here's what I'm working with at the moment:

```
function change_accommodation_post_type_link( $url, $post, $leavename ) {
    if ( 'accommodation' == $post->post_type ) {
        $country_object = get_field('accommodation_country');
        $region_object = get_field('accommodation_region');
        $country = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post($country_object));
        $region = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post($region_object));
        
        $url = site_url('/') . $country . '/' . $region . '/' . $post->post_name . '/';
    }

    return $url;
}

function try_accommodation_before_page_in_parse_request( $wp ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    if ( array_key_exists( 'name', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        $post_name = $wp->query_vars['name'];

        $id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = %s AND post_name = %s ",
            'accommodation', $post_name
        ) );

        if ( $id ) {
            $wp->query_vars['accommodation'] = $post_name;
            $wp->query_vars['post_type'] = 'accommodation';
        }

    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'try_accommodation_before_page_in_parse_request' );

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'change_accommodation_post_type_link', 10, 3 );
```

Based on this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/305011

This works in as far as it changes the URL in the back-end, and it doesn't break any other pages, but it doesn't work. For example, the "Evergreen" accommodation URL is changed to /costa-rica/tortuguero/evergreen/ but that returns a 404.
I have to manually put /accommodation/evergreen/ into the URL bar to see the post.

This is my first time playing with URLs/permastructs, but this is fundamental to the client, and I'm running out of options (and time).

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

If it helps, here's the code I had which almost worked, using wp_rewrite:

```
function add_rewrite_rules(){
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('accommodation', '%country%/%region%/%accommodation%/', false);
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('region', '%region-country%/%region%/', false);
}

function permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename){
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    if ($post->post_type != 'accommodation' && $post->post_type != 'region' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft'))) {
        return $permalink;
    } else if($post->post_type = 'accommodation') {
        $country_object = get_field( 'accommodation_country');
        $region_object = get_field( 'accommodation_region');
        $country = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post($country_object));
        $region = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post($region_object));

        $permalink = str_replace('%country%', $country, $permalink);
        $permalink = str_replace('%region%', $region, $permalink);

        return $permalink;

    } else if($post->post_type == 'region') {

        $region_country_object = get_field('region_country');
        $region_country = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post($region_country_object));

        $permalink = str_replace('%region-country%', $region_country, $permalink);
        
        return $permalink;
    }
}

add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_rules');
add_filter('post_type_link', 'permalinks', 10, 3);
```

This code worked for both CPTs but every page on the site then returned a 404 error. Is there some way I could maybe tweak this and have it working?

Comment: `accommodation_country` should have been a taxonomy not a post meta/custom field, there will be a big performance hit because of this. This Q would have been much easier if it was a taxonomy. Note that none of your code touches rewrite rules, and there are no rewrite rule APIs used in that code, `post_type_link` is not a rewrite rule filter, it is just a final filter for displaying the url of a post in HTML, it has no control over the actual URL

Comment: Or better yet, why not set the parent post to the region CPT and let WordPress do it all automagically?

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm trying to minimize the amount of work that the client has to do from their end. As they're already populating the country and region fields it made sense to use that information rather than make them do it twice. Regardless, how would I go about setting a Region CPT as the parent of an Accommodation CPT?

Comment: They shouldn't do it twice, infact the region post meta should be eliminated. A single UI that selects the region CPT, that sets the posts parent ID to a region CPT post. Likewise your region CPTs should do the same but with country CPTs. As for how to do it that would be a good answer for someone to write. Unfortunately I am not an ACF developer so any answer I gave you may be completely useless to you

Comment: That sounds great. I looked into it and tried a few things though and I'm not so sure I can figure that out either! What a mess :(

Comment: note that doing this with a rewrite rule would mean you would need to write some regex to match the URLs, and then add in a custom query var, and then use that to fill in a `meta_query` structure. Such a query would be slow and would get slower as your site increases in size. Post parentage however might be doable using only changes to the post type registration, it just needs the post parent Ui to list a different CPT, which I believe there are already questions about that on this stack